# mass change values of arraylist

Tags: java, android, parameters, arraylist, set

I have array list of circles, whitch are drawing by canvas. And everything is OK. But I need change all X,Y coordinates of circles, by during the program.

```
static ArrayList<Circle> mCircles;

private static void createCircles() {
    if (mCircles == null) { 
        mCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    }

    int rana = 66/(koeficient);
    mCircles.add(new Circle(80, 200, rana));
}

public static void AddCircle() {
    int rana = 66/(koeficient);

    mCircles.add(new Circle(80, 200, rana));
}

private void Drawing(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Circle c : mCircles) {
        canvas.drawCircle(c.getCurrentX(), c.getCurrentY(), c.getRadius(),
                            mMalovani);
    }
}

public static Circle findCircleClosestToTouchEvent(float x, float y) {
    Circle c = mCircles.get(mCircles.size() - 1);

    return c;
}
```

public class Circle extends Shape {

```
final float mRadius;




public Circle(float x, float y, float r) {
    super(x, y);
    mRadius = r;
}

final float getRadius() {
    return mRadius;
}
```

}

public class Shape extends Activity {

```
protected float mStartX   = 0f;
protected float mStartY   = 0f;
public float mCurrentX = 30f;   
public float mCurrentY = 30f;   
protected float mActionDownX;       
protected float mActionDownY;       
protected float mActionMoveOffsetX; 
protected float mActionMoveOffsetY;



// x y coordinate of a move action

public Shape (float x, float y) {
    mStartX   = x;
    mStartY   = y;
    mCurrentX = x;
    mCurrentY = y;



}








public void setStartX(float x) { mStartX = x; }

public void setStartY(float y) { mStartY = y; }

public float getCurrentX() { return mCurrentX; }

public float getCurrentY() { return mCurrentY; }







public void setCurrentX(float x) { mCurrentX = x;

}

public void setCurrentY(float y) { mCurrentY = y; }

public void setActionMoveOffsetX(float x) { mActionMoveOffsetX = x; }

public void setActionMoveOffsetY(float y) { mActionMoveOffsetY = y; }

public float getActionMoveOffsetX() { return mActionMoveOffsetX; }

public float getActionMoveOffsetY() { return mActionMoveOffsetY; }

public void setActionDownX(float x) { mActionDownX = x; }

public void setActionDownY(float y) { mActionDownY = y; }

public float getActionDownX() { return mActionDownX; }

public float getActionDownY() { return mActionDownY; }





public void restoreStartPosition() {
    mCurrentX = mStartX;
    mCurrentY = mStartY;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `setCurrentX` and `setCurrentY` methods opposite the getter methods, just loop through the list of circles.

```
  private void changeCoordinates(List<Circle> circles, int x, int y){
       for(Circle c:circles){
          c.setCurrentX(x);
          c.setCurrentY(y);
       }
    }
```

Comment: SetCurrentX, setCurrentY are methods whitch return coordinates of Touchevent for last drawing circle. But I need multiplied by two, all X,Y coordinates from arraylist. I hope I understood your advice correctly.

Comment: @JosefJosef Is `Circle` your own class or from a third party?  Post code for circle.